# Blackberry - Beginning GPS coding, app won't find location

Tags: java, blackberry, gps

I'm learning to use thr Blackberry's GPS and have been following the section of the Beginning Blackberry book dealing with GPS but something in the code is wrong as the app only goes as far as 'Getting location: '. I tried downloading the source from the boom incase I missed something but that didn't work either. I know my device's GPS works as I've tested the sample app from the SDK. Below is my code.

LocationHandler.java

```
public class LocationHandler extends Thread{
    private MyScreen screen;

    public LocationHandler(MyScreen screen){
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public void  run(){
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(50);
        criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(50);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_HIGH);

        try{
            screen.setMessage("Getting location...");
            LocationProvider provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
            Location location = provider.getLocation(-1);

            QualifiedCoordinates qualifiedCoordinates = location.getQualifiedCoordinates();

            screen.setLocation(qualifiedCoordinates.getLongitude(), qualifiedCoordinates.getLatitude());
            String message = "Successfully got location, method: ";

            int method = location.getLocationMethod();

            if((method & Location.MTA_UNASSISTED)==Location.MTA_ASSISTED){
                message += "Unassisted GPS";
            }

            if((method & Location.MTE_CELLID)==Location.MTE_CELLID){
                message += "Cell site";
            }

            message += "\nHorizontal (Longitude) Accuracy: ";
            message += qualifiedCoordinates.getHorizontalAccuracy();

            message += "\nVertical (latitude) Accuracy: ";
            message += qualifiedCoordinates.getVerticalAccuracy();

            screen.setMessage(message);
        }catch(LocationException e){
            screen.setMessage("Location Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){
            screen.setMessage("InteruptedException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

MyScreen.java

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    private LabelField latitudeLbl;
    private LabelField longitudeLbl;
    private RichTextField messageField;

    public MyScreen()
    {        
    HorizontalFieldManager latManager = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    latManager.add(new LabelField("Latitude: "));
    latitudeLbl = new LabelField("");
    latManager.add(latitudeLbl);

    add(latManager);

    HorizontalFieldManager longManager = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    longManager.add(new LabelField("Longitude: "));
    longitudeLbl = new LabelField("");
    longManager.add(longitudeLbl);

    add(longManager);
    messageField = new RichTextField();
    add(messageField);
    }

    private void update(){
        LocationHandler handler = new LocationHandler(this);
        handler.start();
    }

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
        menu.add(new MenuItem("Update", 10, 10) {
        public void run() {
        update();
        }
        });
    }

    public void setLocation(double longitude, double latitude){
        synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){
            longitudeLbl.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
            latitudeLbl.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
        }
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){
            messageField.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to detect whether you get a `LocationException` at `LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria)`. If yes, then OS fails to find matching to your criteria LP, so try to use another criteria.

If it does return a valid LP, then it still may fail on `provider.getLocation(-1)`. There are various exceptions/cases. Check the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html#getLocation%28int%29) for details. In most cases here you get either `LocationException` (if the location couldn't be retrieved or if the timeout period expired) or `SecurityException` (if the calling application does not have a permission to query the location information).

Comment: BTW, BB GPS API just sucks. It's very difficult to create a nice GPS app using their API. If you develop for OS 5 or 6, then you can get benefits from newer BB GPS API (the BlackBerry extensions to JSR 179). Check the net.rim.device.api.gps.BlackBerryLocationProvider class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arhimed. How would I check for a LocationException at that line? BTW I was debugging on a device, but when I tried debugging on the simulator it worked.

Comment: By wrapping the line with a try-catch block. Simulator does a bad job simulating GPS: (1) it ignores permissions model (acts as if all app permissions are set to 'Allow'), (2) it provides location updates instantly while on a real device it can be a time consuming action.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried wrapping getLocation() and getInstance and neither returned any exception so I'm going to follow your advice and look into the newer api's.